# NSTextFIeld not editable in Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting, xcode8

I m working on an older non-ARC (Mac OS Project) and i found an issue in **`NSTextField`** not responding to touch events and **`KeyPress`** events only in Mac OS X 10.11.6. On pressing the **`NSButton`** it is showing the content and stuck by showing the focus ring, in **`NStextField`**.

How can i solve this issue?
Also why this happens only in this OS version? any idea?

Comment: Which `NSbutton`? Is it one `NSTextField` or all `NSTextField`s? Do mouse clicks work? Maybe something is wrong and it accidentally works on other versions of macOS. I don't think it's ARC related.

Comment: all NSTextFields where not working.. when performing mouse click older typed values displaying. I f it is not related to ARC. then what is the possibility @Willeke

Comment: Did you subclass `NSTextField` or implement delegate methods? Do you change the first responder in code? What does the button do? Are the system preferences (especially Full Keyboard Access) the same in all OSs?

Comment: I found keyWindow getting nil in button press